# logout_then_login in Django

Tags: django

I would like to allow the user to logout and redirect him directly to the login page. In Django User Authenication Page(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/),

```
logout_then_login(request[, login_url])
Logs a user out, then redirects to the login page.

URL name: No default URL provided

Optional arguments:

login_url: The URL of the login page to redirect to. Defaults to settings.LOGIN_URL if not supplied.
```

The problem i face is then i click the page, it reloads the page instead of going to the login page.

My code is below:

```
@login_required
def main(request):
    """
    main view
    """

    path = reverse('home', kwargs={'userpk': request.user.pk})

    return HttpResponseRedirect(path)

@login_required
def home(request, userpk):
    """
    home page view
    """

    if int(userpk) != request.user.pk:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    return render(request,
                  'lex/main.html',
                  dictionary={'user': request.user,
                              'userpk': userpk})
def logoutnlogin(request):
    """
    Logout n login back
    """
    return logout_then_login(request,login_url=main(request))
```

I think i am doing some mistake not sure where.. Need some guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide url of login page, so the line should be

```
return logout_then_login(request,login_url='/login'))
```

Assuming `/login` is your login url, or you can use `reverse` with name of your login url in `urls.py`

Comment: is it possible to pass in another function into login_url part?

Comment: @lakesh I'm not sure you can pass the function, but you can try another url. If that new url needs authentication, then you have to redirect to login page appropriately may be using _login_required_ decorator.